# Error in creating google datalab instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to follow the [Datalab: Notebook in the Cloud video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu57QKNHaiY) , and when executing the `datalab create ai-adventures` command, I encountered this error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The user does not have access to service account '*@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: '*@gmail.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account
```

Few things to note;

- I'm the project owners.
- I've tried to create a new service account
  `tutorial@*.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and that didn't work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Edit 1**

Below is the information, as you can see when checking through `gcloud auth list` directive, I'm the owner, yet it tells me that I don't have access.

```
~ ⌚ 18:40:34
$ datalab create ai-adventures-3 --machine-type=n1-standard-4 --zone=us-central1-b
Creating the disk ai-adventures-3-pd
Creating the instance ai-adventures-3
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The user does not have access to service account 'service-510602609611@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'XXX@gmail.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account

A nested call to gcloud failed, use --verbosity=debug for more info.

~ ⌚ 15:02:59
$ gcloud auth list
          Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       XXX@gmail.com
        AAA@gmail.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`



~ ⌚ 15:03:45
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your error in my own project using different ways to connect to it, with different users and accounts services.

And I found something that may help you.

- First, I created a new VMInstance with OS `debian-9-drawfork-v20200207`.
- I logged in to this new instance through SSH
- But when I attempted to create this datalab instance with the command

`datalab create --verbosity=debug  example-datalab-2 --machine-type n1-standard-1`

I received an error.

- Then I send the following command

`gcloud auth list`

And I received something like:

```
                  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
   *   XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

It means that if I tried to create the new datalab instance with this Account Service, but this account doesn’t have the roles to create the notebook instance.

- Then I changed the user with  `gcloud auth login` command to an account with the owner role and re-ran the `datalab create` command and it worked.
- To corroborate that it is working well I used the command
  `datalab connect example-datalab-2`

And I received something like

```
Connecting to example-datalab-2.
This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair. To manage these keys, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
This tool needs to create the directory [/home/directory/.ssh] before
being able to generate SSH keys.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
.
.
.
Updating project ssh metadata...done.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.

The connection to Datalab is now open and will remain until this command is killed.
Click on the *Web Preview* (square button at top-right), select *Change port > Port 8081*, and start using Datalab.
```

Then If I access to http://localhost:8081/ I can see:

[image]

It is worth mentioning that I received another error message at my first attempt

`ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.list) User [user@example.com] does not have permission to access project [myproject] (or it may not exist): Cloud Source Repositories API has not been used in project xxxxxxxx before or it is disabled.`

I fixed this issue enabling the service with the command

`gcloud beta services enable sourcerepo.googleapis.com`

On the other hand, in order that you can troubleshoot this issue more accurately , I recommend to re-run the command with the following debug flag to help diagnose the problem:

`datalab create --verbosity=debug datalab-instance-name`

Also, I have found 2 guides that can help you with your task:

- [Quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart) that shows you how to use the datalab command line tool to set up and open Google Cloud Datalab.
- [Create a new notebook instance guide](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new).

I hope you find this information useful.

---

#### Edit 1

Regarding the Service Account you mentioned `tutorial@*.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, I’ve found the following [document](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/datalab-team#project_owner_creates_instances_for_other_team_members) where it says that you can use a service account instead of the default service account to create your datalab, but you need to add the following roles:

`roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1`

`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`

So, please check if your SA has these roles and then you can run the same command + `--service-account` something like:

`datalab create ai-adventures --service-account=tutorial@*.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

You could see more information in the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create#--service-account_service_account).

This question is more interesting than I thought and I’ve encountered several issues using Datalab, we could take in consideration that the video you [mentioned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu57QKNHaiY) has been posted on Jan 11, 2018 and as Google Cloud Platform is evolving very fast, something that could work on that date could completely change 2 years later.

With this, I recommend you to use the [*AI Platform Notebooks page*](https://console.cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/?_ga=2.267278988.305402083.1598273128-638966553.1591892739) since it has similar features as Datalab, and according with the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/release-notes#March_31_2020) it was released as Generally Available on March 31st, 2020.

Upon trying it out, it seems that it could fit your use case and it also has capabilities to connect to Bigquery through the use of the R notebook.

Comment: So I've tried the `gcloud auth list` directive and it confirms that my email (I'm the owner) is selected, I've even tried to re-login and reset the project, yet the error persists.

I've tried `Quickstart guide` and create `New Notebook guide`, but I ran into the same error.

What I have noticed is that when creating an instance GCP will also create a new account for it, for me it was `service-510602609611@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and disregard the owner's account.
I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Could you please try with the following command:`datalab create ai-adventures-3 --machine-type=n1-standard-4 --zone=us-central1-b` this command should provide an output like this:`Creating the disk ai-adventures-3-pd
Creating the instance ai-adventures-3
Created [https://../myproject/zones/us-central1-b/instances/ai-adventures-3].
Connecting to ai-adventures-3.
This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair. To manage these keys, see https://..-removing-ssh-keys
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/` Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried the command and added the output on the original post, still the same error appeared.  Although when I checked the web-console I can see `ai-adventures-3-pd` disk has been created.

Comment: @badcoder I've edited my answer with the last information I was able to find. Please take a look to it.

Comment: Thank you @Jose I think I'll switch to AI Platform Notebooks instead.

Comment: I'm happy to know the answer was useful, in order to help the community in the future, could you please accept or upvote the answer? Thanks